# react-router-dom gives blank page after build

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-router-dom

Whenever I have a React project that uses react-router-dom it works perfectly on the development mode with the command "npm start", but when I run the build and deploy it to an apache server, for example, I get a blank page with the title and favicon of the project.

Here's some example of the routes I've been writing:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes as Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Hello from "./pages/Hello";

function Routes() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
                <Route path='/hello' element={<Hello />} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default Routes;
```

index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import Routes from './Routes';
import './index.css';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Routes />
);
```

Comment: Review the CRA [deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) docs to see if there's a relevant section for the server environment you are trying to serve your app from.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out what was going on. I used create-react-app and it assumes that you're trying to host your project at de root path of a domain which in my case was not true. I was trying to host the app at "localhost/routes" and create-react-app assumed it was just "localhost". With a few changes I could get my code to work the way I expected.

Add basename prop to BrowserRouter:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes as Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Hello from "./pages/Hello";

function Routes() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter basename='/routes'>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
                <Route path='/hello' element={<Hello />} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default Routes;
```

I also had to put this line of code into the package.json file:

```
  "homepage": ".",
```